# Adding entries to a properties file before maven compile phase

Tags: maven, build, properties, automation, jenkins

We are using [maven filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) for properties file, in which we inject the build number and time from out Jenkins server.

It would be cool if we could add there properties to our app.local.properties file dynamically, thus not forcing each project maintainer to add them (one time operation, but annoying never the less).

I would like to

- Add params to a properties file, before the filter plugin kicks in.
- If the destination properties file does not exist -> create it and then add.
- I need to edit the properties file in the target directory (the src/main/resources dir should remain untouched).

Nice to have:

- Add configuration settings only if they aren't already defined in the file (to avoid duplicating entries added manually)

Is there some maven plugin / hook that I can tap into to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could build a custom maven build extension and retrieve those properties dynamically from a cetntral service and inject them into the POM in memory, right after the build process starts. Indeed that is how we solved this very problem in our company setup.

I've just posted a full recipe [to this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489311/feasibility-of-getting-maven-aggregator-pom-to-inject-properties-into-module-pom/16442637#16442637)

Comment: Thank you, this sucks less then all other solutions to this problem. By "sucks" I mean that changes to MySpecialExtension now need to managed to avoid version conflicts (should you wish to rebuild a 7 months old artifacts for ex.). I'm accepting this, as it seems like the most suitable solution found.

Comment: thats true -- at least the dependency to a specific version of MySpecialExtension can be stated clearly within the "consuming" POM.

Answer (score 0):

I see a conflict here:

- Add params to a properties file, before the filter plugin kicks in.

So you need to edit the properties in `src/main/resources`, as filter plugin works on these, but at the same time:

- I need to edit the properties file in the target directory (the src/main/resources dir should remain untouched).

What I understand is, you'd like to do this filtering somehow "on the fly". I don't think Maven mechanisms could do it; I'd do it completely with the [Antrun plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) (excluding the property file from Maven handling) which I'd invoke in the `process-resources` phase. There's a [propertyFile task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/propertyfile.html) for editing and saving property files; after saving your changes, you could process the file once more with the [regexp task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replaceregexp.html), for example, to apply your filters.

Comment: That sounds pretty much like what I would be doing, I'll try that and update.