# Sharing dynamically generated properties between sibling modules

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I'm trying to create a Maven plugin for running tests in isolation in a service-oriented architecture. Given a project layout like:

```
Service
|- webapp
|- int-test
```

I want to:

1. Generate property values dynamically by calling out to configurable "property suppliers". One such property supplier might call out to a web service to get an unused account ID under which test data will be staged.
2. Substitute these values into the property files of the webapp and int-test modules.
3. Start up the webapp
4. Run the tests.

I assume the best way to do this would be to add the plugin's configuration to the parent POM, and then a user can simply check out the project, cd into the parent pom's directory and execute the plugin's goal to run the tests against a locally running service.

I'm not quite sure how one would do step 2 above. Ideally, I'd rather not have the plugin change the property files in `int-test/src/test/resources` or `webapp/src/main/config` because then people might check these changes in by mistake. I'd rather the substitutions only appear in the respective `target/` directories.

I've seen that filtering can be used to solve similar problems, but I haven't seen any solutions involving sharing dynamically generated properties between modules.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: How about, write your dynamically generated file to a properties file. Then read the properties using the maven properties plugin[1]. Then run filtering based on those properties [2]. (AFAIU, we can give maven properties as filtering variables)

[1] http://haroon.sis.utoronto.ca/zarar/properties-maven-plugin/index.html
[2] http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

Comment: Well the problem is that the properties need to be read at the parent POM level and then filtered into the child project's property files.

Answer (score 0):

you could build a custom maven build extension and retrieve those properties dynamically from a cetntral service and inject them into the POM in memory, right after the build process starts. Indeed that is how we solved this very problem in our company setup.

I've just posted a full recipe [to this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489311/feasibility-of-getting-maven-aggregator-pom-to-inject-properties-into-module-pom/16442637#16442637)